# how to copy all files from a folder to another folder in c#

Tags: c#, .net, copy

Please let me know how to copy all files within a folder to another folder in c# .net.

Currently I am using :

```
int j = 1;
int k = 1;

    for (j = 1; j < 5; j++)
    {

        for (k = 1; k < 32; k++)
        {

            string sourcePath = @Desktop_location + "\Test" + k + ".log";

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(sourcePath))
            {
                File.Copy(@Desktop_location + "\\Statistics\\Server" + j + "\Test" + k + ".log", @Desktop_location + "\\Statistics\\Transfer\\test" + j + k + ".log");
                //Console.WriteLine("Test Result");
            }
            else
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Test");
```

Comment: does this work? Would you like to improve on it in some fashion?

Comment: please someone help me how to copy all files from multiple folders to a single folder.Also, please suggest if the file having same name exist in more than 1 folder but it's contenet are different.

Comment: what are those Magic Numbers '5' and '32'?

Comment: sometimes simpler is better: why don't spawn xcopy ?

Comment: You'll need to tell us what you'd like to happen, then we can tell you how. Otherwise there is no right answer. Merge, Replace, Exception or something else?

Comment: Something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx?

Comment: It seems to me a university assignment.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
```

See [Getting files from a directory](http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/)

```
string myPath = @"C:\Test";
foreach (string file in filePaths)
{
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
    if (!File.Exists(info.FullName))
    {
       File.Copy(info.FullName, newPath);
    }
}
```

See [Using FileInfo Class](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fileinfo), you don't actually require it here but it contains a lot of useful functionality for working with files and folders.
Reading it will help you with planning your application.

Comment: Only one file is getting copied using this code. Please help:

Comment: @GulshanAnand you are making zero effort and just asking me to do it for you so I am no longer very inclined to help you.
This should be easy for a beginner to resolve. If you don't know how to debug read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn) article.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to copy **all** files, you can do it like this (copies all contents including directories):

```
foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(sourcePath, destinationPath));
}

foreach (var newPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(sourcePath, destinationPath));
}
```

Comment: well please suggest if file with the same name exist in more than one folder but i want to retain both the files in the folder in whcih i am copying the files

Comment: @GulshanAnand That is beginner logic, please make an effort to code it yourself. You will never learn from copying and pasting other peoples code.

Comment: Depends on how you want those duplicates to be named. Are you OK with naming conventions like Explorer uses, i.e. it will add "(1)" suffixes the end of the filename?

Comment: Yes alexander if it appends 1,2,3 and so on then that wil work for me.